# JavaScript Add Array of Objects to Specific key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm struggling with adding an array of objects to the existing array of objects with Vue.js.
What I'm actually trying to do is making form repeater in another form repeater.
I managed to make the first one without problems but the second one is making me really nervous.

I tried with splice and push functions but it's not working as expected.

So this is a function for the first form repeater (and it's working)

BTW: parent is defined as array in state.

```
addParent: function () {
            this.form.parent.push({
                name: '',
                age: '',
            });
        },
```

So the output looks like this:

```
parent: [
            {
                name: 'My name',
                age: 32,
            }
        ]
```

So in this object, I need to add a child, to look like so:

```
parent: [
            {
                name: 'My name',
                age: 32,
                child: [
                    {
                        name: 'My children',
                        school: 'Elementary'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

And I'm trying to do it like so:

```
addChildren: function (index) {
            this.form.parent.splice([index], 0, {
                child: {
                    name: '',
                    school: '',
                }
            });
        },
```

And it's not working for some reason, it's adding new array of parent and object of child.
And this is other way that I tried to do it:

```
addChildrenSecoundTry: function (index) {
            var dd = [];
            dd[index] = {
                    child: {
                      name: '',
                      school: '',
                  }
                };

            this.form.packages.splice([index], 0, dd);

        },
```

But no success.

I tried with push, passing a key from a parent, but it's always giving an error that push is not a function.

Here is a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/rade-ilijev/pen/zYNvgqK) example that I made to make more clear my vision.

Answer (score 0):

Try out to spread the original keys with new one (`child`) at the given index

```
addChildren: function (index) {
            this.form.parent.splice(index, 1, {
                ...this.form.parent[index],
                child: {
                    name: '',
                    school: '',
                }
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the array/object to parent object. I have used a ternary, to check if 'child' key exists, and if it does, push the object to it, else create new key, with object inside array.

```
addChildren: function (index) { this.form.parent[index].child =
this.form.parent[index].child ? this.form.parent[index].child.push({name: '',
school: '',}) : [ {name: '', school: '',} ], } }); },
```